# Should client send the whole image or it's reference to server?

Tags: image, server, microservices, backend

I have a service A, an api gateway B and a client C, client C will send request with an image to B, B will send it to A and A will process that image. So should C send the whole image to B in order that A receives the image directly from B (option 1) or C send the reference of the image (image url) in order that A get the image from the image url for processing (option 2) ? Which option do I need to have higher performance ?

[image: 2 options]

Comment: Option 2 puts far less load on the gateway (B) and allows you to parallelise and scale the Image Processing Service  (A) if demand increases. Option 1 is architecturally simpler and conceptually simpler. The hard part of the service is likely to be implementing the algorithms at (A) and architecting the API at (B) - neither of those is likely to need much change if you started simply with Option 1 and needed to change to Option 2 later. Just my 2 pence.

Comment: On the other hand, if the images are tiny and the processing very small and you want to put thousands of tiny images through per second, you would do better to send the image through the gateway because you wouldn't want to increase latency by making the the Image Processing Service (A) have to go out to AWS after it had received the request through Gateway (B).

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for supporting me. I have an additional question, you said that Option 2 allows me to parallelise and scale the Image Processing Service (A) if demand increases, so if I choose Option 1, why does it not allow me to do those like Option 2 ?

Comment: I am just imagining (B) might have bandwidth problems if you try to pump large volumes of data from many clients through a single machine. If you have multiple image processors they will all be able to retrieve the data they need from AWS in parallel.

Comment: @MarkSetchell So does it have only problems in (B) ? Do I still scale (A) to multiple image processors or multiple machines for receiving a large volumes of data from (B) in parallel without get images from AWS ?. I'm not sure whether those are correct or not.